# Disable CountDownTimer after leaving the activity

Tags: android

I have a CountDownTimer instance which is initialized in a recyclerView adapter class. I create an alertDialog after the countdown reaches to zero. I want to stop/disable the timer if I press the back button and leave the activty in which the fragment containing the adapter is bound.

Unfortunately I cannot check the current activity in an adapter and if I leave without cancelling the timer my app crashes as the context changes.

How do I cancel it as soon as I leave the activity?

Answer (score 1):

Override `onBackPressed()` and call `cancel()` method on Timer. Like this...

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
    mTimer.cancel() // Call cancel on timer instance
}
```

Also, if you want to stop the timer when the activity is not visible, you can call the cancel method in `onPause()` of your activity/fragment.

Comment: not sure if this works with nested classes, like Activity -> RecyclerView -> Timer, timer might be inaccessible from above.

Answer (score 0):

When your timer expires, check if the `Activity` is still running with this snippet:

```
if ( context instanceof Activity ) {
    Activity activity = (Activity)context;
    if ( activity.isFinishing() ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

and, obviously, don't use the `context` if the `Activity` is dead.

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty option for doing this here is one of them there is a method as `onDetachedFromRecyclerView()` in your recyclerView.Adapter class
 override this method and notify your ViewHolder to stops countDownTimer for notifying view holders your can make them to listen to some event like `stopTimer()` and you can call this method for stopping timer ! in your activity where you are setting adapter to your recyclerView  override onPause or onStop method and add this code `recyclerView.setAdapter(null);` this will triggers the `onDetachedFromRecyclerView()` method and makes your countDownTimer stop also you can check the `view.getContext()==null` in your countDownTimer if the context was null it means the context has been changed